# MySQL innoDB index storage type not specified

Tags: mysql, indexing, mysql-workbench, b-tree

I'm using MySQL Workbench to manage my database architecture.  I've noticed that if I create an index, there is a section for Index Options. By default, the Storage Type is blank, with a block size of 0.  The pull down has options for BTREE and RTREE, but it allows me to save it without anything selected.

Since I haven't specified the storage type, is it actually saving the index correctly?  Going back and altering the table to use BTREE causes MySQL Workbench to hang for several minutes while it reindexes the table. So I'm wondering if not specifying a Storage Type causes the index to not work properly.

Comment: When you are not specifying the storage type MySql uses the default storage type.

Comment: Do you happen to know what the default storage type is for InnoDB or how to get it?

Comment: you can use the query `SHOW ENGINES` to get the engines.

Comment: InnoDB **is** the storage type, so it cannot have a default type. Your schema can have a default storage engine, however.

Comment: Mike, In this context 'storage type' refers to the storage type of the index, not which engine is being used to store the schema/database.

Answer (score 2):

> All InnoDB indexes are B-trees where the index records are stored in
>   the leaf pages of the tree. The default size of an index page is 16KB.
>   When new records are inserted, InnoDB tries to leave 1/16 of the page
>   free for future insertions and updates of the index records.

Check these links

- [Physical Structure of an
  Index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-physical-structure.html)
- [Clustered and Secondary Indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-index-types.html)